# Creating ellipse in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, buffer

I want to create an ellipse around a point. I have the lat/longs of the point and the length of semimajor and semi minor axes in a CSV format. Is there a way?

Comment: You may want to remove "buffer" from your problem statement, since what you want to construct is just a spherical or spheroidal ellipse.

Comment: @Vince I have edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**QGIS 3.0**

An example csv

[image]

**Geometry by expression**

[image]

Expression (in the step-3 above):

```
make_ellipse(transform(make_point("lon_dd","lat_dd"), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32653'),  
             "semimajor", "semiminor", "az")
```

Output:

[image]

---

**QGIS (< 3.0)** ... *(Tested in QGIS 2.18.19 on Windows10)*

[**Shape Tools**](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/) Plugin

This time you need to (1) `Add Delimited Text` your csv on WGS84 (EPSG:4326) (2) reproject the point by `Save As`, and (3) set the project CRS to fit with the reprojected point data.

Then, using **Shape Tools**

[image]

The output image is the same.