# Making ellipses on a global data set

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I am getting information on earthquakes that I am going to plot on a map. This consists of a calculated epicentre location and an uncertainty ellipse for the epicentre. This is a global data set, so the epi centre is given in lat / lon and could be anywhere on earth. The parameters for the uncertainty ellipse is given in kilometers. The data typically looks like:

```
Epicenter lat:                 59.0214 +/-   0.1518 [deg]
Epicenter lon:                 14.6805 +/-   0.3193 [deg]
Source depth :                  0.00   [km] Fixed

Epicenter error ellipse:
Major half axis:    23.41 [km]  Minor half axis:    10.97 [km]
Azimuth:       40.8  [deg] Area:         806.77 [km**2]
```

The half axis may be up to a few hundred kms.

I would like to calculate the error ellipse, get it back to lat lon and store it in postgis.

My plan for doing this is:

1. project the epicenter to *some reasonable meter based projection*
2. calculate the error ellipse
3. reproject the error ellipse to lat lon

My problem is what would * some reasonable meter based projection* be? One possibility would of course be to select a UTM zone based on where the epicentre is, but are there any other projections I could use that preserve shape reasonably well within a few hundred kms? (I feel using UTM would be pushing this a bit for those events that are towards the north or the south - I live at 60N, so here the width of a UTM zone is around 150 kms) The easiest would be a single projection that can be used everywhere, but I wouldn't mind using different projections as long as the results makes sense togheter.

Or are there any completely different ways of doing this that I have overlooked?

Comment: Have a look at `_ST_BestSRID(geography)`  and its underlining [function](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/f6def67654c25d812446239036cee44812613748/postgis/geography_measurement.c#L789). They use _"UTM, polar stereographic and mercator as fallback"_

Comment: I believe pyqgis will accept ellipse information in lat/long.  https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Ellipse/QgsEllipse.html  or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283205/creating-ellipse-in-qgis.    You could check your work there and export.

Comment: @JGH, _ST_BestSRID works - kind of. If I have a small enough area, I get 9990xx where xx seems to be the UTM zone, so I could eg make 999032 into 25832 to get ETRS89 zone 32. When I tried select _st_bestSRID('POLYGON((10 10, 10 20,20 20,20 10,10 10))'), it gave me 999229 which I am unable to get anything out of...

Comment: If you were willing to create a custom spatial reference system for each epicenter, the [Stereographic](https://proj.org/operations/projections/stere.html) (conformal azimuthal) projection would be a choice.

Comment: azimuthal equidistant would be the best--but here's a trick. Build the ellipse in any azimuthal equidistant (centered at 0,0 for instance). When you unproject it, then use the customized center point.